# Can I search for part of the key of a HTML5 local storage using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I stored the local storage (HTML5) with key value's format looks like this:

```
Fri May 29 2015 07:30:00 GMT+0700[G]
```

the first part is date-time and second part [G] is some indicators I made.
Can I search for all the indexs/values with the keys contain a specific date?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard API for it, and there is a good reason for it. You should really find some cleaner approach to do what you need. Why don't you use the date string as a key, and put your data as an object into localStorage.

Comment: Well actually I need the key to be unique so I decided to make the time and indicator became the key. I will try to make the key generated automatically and join all the things together. But it will be: [date-time, indicator1, indicator2, value] which will still need a way to query a part of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain a date format while saving and retrieving from localStorage. If the date formats are same for storing and retrieving then it you can work easily with `localStorage`.

```
var date1 = '25 April 2011',
    date2 = '31 October 2010'; 

localStorage.setItem(new Date(date1), '[G]');
localStorage.setItem(new Date(date2), '[G]');
localStorage.setItem(new Date(), '[G]');
```

While retrieving pass the date and time,

```
localStorage.getItem(new Date(date));
```

Comment: Thanks but I joint the Date together with the [G] indicator into one column. If they are separated then it would be the method you posted above.

Comment: You can use a regex expression to split the string. `str.split(str.match('\\[[A-Z]\\]'))`. This will return an array whose 0th index contains the date only. You need to add further logic as per your project need.

Comment: Yes but I need a lot more logic to search for 1 value of a part together with 1 value of another part and so on with more parts. Well I'm researching the Indexed db because I think I need a real database here. Thanks for your help anyway.